# Hortonworks Hive ODBC Driver DB-240000

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

> DB-240000 ODBC error: [Hortonworks][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic
>   analysis error thrown in server while executing query.
>
> Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED:
>   ParseException line 1:12 cannot recognize input near 'ALL_ROWS'
>
> '*' '/' in hint name SQLState: 37000

Sample query

```
WDB-200001 SQL statement 'SELECT  /*+ ALL_ROWS */ A.test FROM table A' could not be executed.
```

Syntax looks right as per documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF51108)

Or is there a missing param on the odbc configuration?
https://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Hortonworks-Hive-ODBC-Driver-User-Guide.pdf

> Use Native Query Key Name Default Value Required UseNativeQuery Clear
>   (0) No Architecting the Future of Big Data Hortonworks Inc. Page 71
>   Description When this option is enabled (1), the driver does not
>   transform the queries emitted by an application, so the native query
>   is used. When this option is disabled (0), the driver transforms the
>   queries emitted by an application and converts them into an equivalent
>   from in HiveQL. Note: If the application is Hive-aware and already
>   emits Hive

1. Could this be an issue with HDP versioning?
2. Is there a missing Param
   in the ODBC connection string?